# how to convert multiline linux commands to one line of command

Tags: linux, shell, mysql

Can someone please explain me how to use ">" and "|" in linux commands and convert me these three lines into one line of code please?

```
mysqldump --user=*** --password=*** $db --single-transaction -R > ${db}-$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql
tar -cf ${db}-$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql.tar ${db}-$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql
gzip ${db}-$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql.tar
rm ${db}-$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql (after conversion I guess this line will be useless)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU `tar` program can itself do the compression normally done by `gzip`. You can use the `-z` flag to enable this. So the `tar` and `gzip` could be combined into:

```
tar -zcf ${db}-$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql.tar.gz ${db}-$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql
```

Getting `tar` to read from standard input for archiving is not a simple task but I would question its necessity in this particular case.

The intent of `tar` is to be able to package up a multitude of files into a single archive file but, since it's only one file you're processing (the output stream from `mysqldump`), you don't *need* to `tar` it up, you can just pipe it straight into `gzip` itself:

```
mysqldump blah blah | gzip > ${db}-$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql.gz
```

That's because `gzip` will compress standard input to standard output if you don't give it any file names.

This removes the need for any (possibly very large) temporary files during the compression process.

Comment: .tgz extension gives error while extracting. I guess it should be .gz right?

Comment: @Ergec: sorry, yes, that was a hangover from a cut'n'paste operation when I was still using tar. Fixed now.

Comment: "_Getting `tar` to read from standard input for archiving is not a simple task_" -- I just tried this by making a symlink to `/dev/stdin`, but the corresponding entry in the tar file showed up as empty.  (I'm almost relieved it didn't work.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use next script:

```
#!/bin/sh
USER="***"
PASS="***"
DB="***"

mysqldump --user=$USER --password=$PASS $DB --single-transaction -R | gzip > ${DB}-$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql.gz
```

You can learn more about "|" here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix). I can say that this construction moves output of mysqldump command to the standard input of gzip command, so that is like you connect output of one command with input of other via pipeline.

Comment: This gives you a gzipped sql file, not a gzipped tarball containing a sql file.  As @paxdiablo says, that's *probably* ok (but there might be a specific requirements for a `*.tgz` file).

Comment: @keith, it seems I don't need tar but that's another good question, in what conditions I may need tar?

Comment: @Ergec:  I don't know specifically, but you might have some tool that needs `*.tgz` files and can't deal with `.gz` files.  If you don't, then that's great; don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

I dont see the point in using tar: You just have one file, and for compression you call gzip explicit. Tar is used to archive/pack multiple files into one.

You cammandline should be (the dump command is  shorted, but I guess you will get it):

```
mysqldump .... | gzip > filename.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

To append the commands together in one line, I'd put && between them.  That way if one fails, it stops executing them.  You could also use a semicolon after each command, in which case each will run regardless if the prior command fails or not.

You should also know that tar will do the gzip for you with a "z" option, so you don't need the extra command.

Paxdiablo makes a good point that you can just pipe mysqldump directly into gzip.